# How to add a bottom margin to the div on select the option with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, html-select

I'm trying to add the margin of the select div when the value selected
I'm not an expert in the javascript
I found javascript on another blog but I think that does not work
Help me to do that

Here is my code

```
<style>
.container{
border:2px solid black;
margin-top: 20px;}

</style>
<div class="html-code-output">
<div class="main">
    <p>Select an option to show the value and text of that option.</p>
    <select class="addon-select">
        <option value="">Select  a Option</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
<div class="container">
<h4>Add a margin when we select the an option</h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>

jQuery('.addon-select').on('change', function () {
    let val = $(this).val();
    $(".main").css("margin-bottom", "1rem");
    $(".main('" + val + "') ").css("margin-bottom", "5rem");
});;

</script>
```

Comment: What element is the second jQuery selector supposed to select?

Comment: that second jquery element looks like it has some syntax error, what are you trying to do there? also where is the `product-addon` element which you are trying to add the style into?

Comment: your html has some typos as well `<option value=>Select  a Option</option>` if you want this 1st option to have no value then it should look like this `<option value="">Select  a Option</option>` and this `<h4>Add a margin when we select the an option</h1>` you can't open `<h4>` tag and close it with `<h1>`

Comment: let me make it corect

Answer (score 0):

If you have one element which you want to change its margin-bottom depending on what is selected on the select:

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="item">
  Item 
</div>

<select onchange="selectFunction(this)">
  <option value="">Select option</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</body>
```

JS

```
function selectFunction(selected){
    var selectedOption = $(selected).val();
  
  $(".item").css("margin-bottom",selectedOption*3);
}
```

If you have many items, and you want to change the padding of one of them depending on which option is selected on the select:

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="item">
  Item  1
</div>
<div class="item">
  Item  2
</div>
<div class="item">
  Item  3
</div>
<div class="item">
  Item  4
</div>

<select onchange="selectFunction(this)">
  <option value="">Select option</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</body>
```

JS

```
function selectFunction(selected){
$(".item").css("margin-bottom",0);
    var selectedOption = $(selected).val();
  selectedOption --;
  
  
  
  $(".item").eq(selectedOption).css("margin-bottom",10);
}
```